# Tensor product over another tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring and let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-algebras. Construct $A\otimes_R B$, the $R$-algebra given by tensor product. Let then $C$ and $D$ be two $A\otimes_RB$-algebras. Clearly $C$ and $D$ are also $R$-algebras, via restriction of scalars. Is it true, at least under some flatness condition, that $C\otimes_R D\cong C\otimes_{A\otimes_R B}D$, canonically, as $R$-algebras?

Comment: In general this is  false. Take $R$ to be a field, $A,B$ polynomial rings in one variable over $R$. Then $S=A\otimes_R B$ is a polynomial ring in two variables over $R$. Take $C=D=S$. Then, $C\otimes_R D$ is a polynomial ring in four variables over $R$, while $C\otimes_S D$ is a polynomial ring in two variables over $R$.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

Comment: @Mohan: It seems to me your comment should be promoted to an answer.